# Removing selected rows from opencv::Mat?

Tags: arrays, opencv, vector, mat

For some reasons I need to filter out rows of a Mat. (I need to filter out some descriptors of ORB)

Which way do you suggest me? I haven't find any method to remove a single row from a Mat. 
So I was thinking I could iteratively inserting the good rows in a new Mat.

C++ pseudocode (with removing):

```
Mat desc;
ORB(myImage,cv::noArray,kp,desc);
matcher->match( myPreviousDesc, desc, matches );

for(auto i=0;i<matches.size();i++) {
   if (some conditions) {
      Remove the ith row of desc:
      erase( desc.row( matches[i].queryIdx ) ); // pseudo
   }
}
```

How would you erase a single row from a Mat after checking for some conditions (or adding only the selected row in a new Mat) ?

Or how to add a new row iteratively to a new Mat ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iteratively adding a new row is straightforward with [`cv::Mat::push_back()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-push-back).

Adding only good descriptors might look like this:

```
cv::Mat good_descriptors;   
for (auto i = 0; i < matches.size(); ++i)
{
    if (/*something*/)
    {
        cv::Mat row = desc.row(matches[i].queryIdx);
        good_descriptors.push_back(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Explicitly declaring `row` isn't strictly necessary. I did it for readability. And `reshape()` isn't necessary unless you want to be *extra* sure--the original number of columns is preserved.